# scroll image that has text description using view pager in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager

My current design lets me swipe (left and right swipe) through images like this:[current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BwMD.png)

But what I really want to do is change it a bit so that I have a text description at the bottom. The text description changes when the image change. The new design is  like this:

[new design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9Zcs.png)

I'm not sure how do I achieved this design? For example how do I draw those three circles? How do I make the text change when the image changed? Can anyone please advise?

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages = new int[] {
        R.drawable.chiang_mai,
        R.drawable.himeji,
        R.drawable.petronas_twin_tower,
        R.drawable.ulm
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mImages.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
      return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      Context context = MainActivity.this;
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
      int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
          R.dimen.padding_medium);
      imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
      imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
      imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
      ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
      return imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
      ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }
  }
}
```

//activity_main

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/view_pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Did you try my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand, you want both image and text to be scrolled, and you need indicator at the bottom.

So you change your `PagerAdapter` to sth like this:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private int[] mImages ;
    private Context mContext;

    public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, int[] mImages) {
        mContext = context;
        this.mImages = mImages;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout_with_image_and_text,container,false);


        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.your_image_view);
        TextView textView=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.your_text_view)
        //.. load image and text you got from constructor
        container.addView(layout, 0);
        return layout;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if(mImages!=null)
            return mImages.length;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }
}
```

For indicator,  use [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/library/src/com/viewpagerindicator/CirclePageIndicator.java) and put it below `ViewPager` in xml

```
<your_package.CirclePageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:fillColor="@color/primary_color"
            app:pageColor="@color/white"
            app:strokeColor="@color/primary_color"
            android:padding="4dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you need to inflate a custom layout containing an `ImageView` and a `TextView` below it (or any other arrangement you may need). Then modify your `PagerAdapter` to inflate this custom layout with the image and the text. This is just to give you a better idea.

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
      Context context = container.getContext();      // I feel this is a better implementation
      CustomLayout layout = new CustomLayout(context);   

      // This is a custom layout that you could create
      // you could init a LinearLayout and add an 
      // ImageView and a TextView to it, your call :)

      // Set image and text in your view accortind to 'position'

      return layout;
    }
```

Comment: thanks @SlashG, nope Ideally I want the textview to change when the Image changed

Comment: Modifying my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,you need to create array for texts,

```
private int imageArr[] = { R.drawable.f, R.drawable.g, R.drawable.h,
                              R.drawable.i, R.drawable.j};  

private String[] stringArray = new String[] { "first", "sec","third","fourth","fifth"};
```

initialize your adapter

```
adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(this, imageArr, stringArray );
```

make your adapter like

```
int imgArray [];
String[] stringArray;
public ImagePagerAdapter(Activity act, int[] imgArra, String[] stringArr) {
    activity = act;
    imgArray = imgArra;
    stringArray = stringArr;
}
```

then get the position

```
txt.setText(stringArray[position]);
```

See [this](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-viewpager-gallery-images-and-texts-tutorial/) for more